# Convert dataframe into list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I would like to convert a dataframe containing zip codes and relationships between zip codes into a list.

I looked at ways to convert dataframes into lists as well as the spread function.

The first column (`codes1`) contains all zip codes of a zone. The second column (`codes2`) contains the zip codes of the cities related to the first one.

```
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(rep(1:4, c(2,5,4,3)),c(2,4,4,3,6,8,7,1,2,8,7,1,2,3)))
colnames(df)<-c("codes1","codes2")
df
```

I would like to obtain a list like this one, containing for each zip code the related zip codes:

```
l <- list(c(2,4), c(4,3,6,8,7),c(1,2,8,7),c(1,2,3))
l
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just split `codes2` by `codes1`

```
split(x = df$codes2, f = df$codes1)
#$`1`
#[1] 2 4

#$`2`
#[1] 4 3 6 8 7

#$`3`
#[1] 1 2 8 7

#$`4`
#[1] 1 2 3
```

You could also loop through unique values of `codes1` and select relevant value from `codes2`

```
lapply(X = unique(df$codes1),
       FUN = function(x) subset(df$codes2, df$codes1 == x))
#[[1]]
#[1] 2 4

#[[2]]
#[1] 4 3 6 8 7

#[[3]]
#[1] 1 2 8 7

#[[4]]
#[1] 1 2 3
```